# What's the minimum amount of money I need to show to be able to support a UK family visa for my kids?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-citizens, family

I am an UK passport holder and I have got a job offer in UK. I am planning to bring my family with me (wife has Japanese passport and kids have got New Zealand passport). The kids cannot get an UK passport due to my condition on my UK passport

As I don't earn enough in New Zealand and I cannot support their visa now. I have checked the UK government website and realised that I can support their visa if I can bring in an amount of money and leave it in the bank for 6 months.We are looking to sell our stuff in here and so we don't have a large amount at this stage, but by the time when we leave New Zealand, we should have.

Does anyone know what's the minimum amount I need to have in my bank if I want to support their visa after 6 months? I want to apply for their visa at the earliest and does anyone know any other way?

Comment: If I'm reading the info correctly, you'll need yearly income (assuming your wife doesn't work) of 24800. If your salary isn't that high, you can use savings that have been held for over 6 months (I don't think it has to be in the UK) and only the amount over 16k. In addition, you have to divide that amount by 2.5. The result is what you can claim.

Comment: @mkennedy Convert that into an answer. ;)